# How to maximise the life of the Apple battery charger set (for Magic Mouse) batteries?

Tags: battery, mouse, charging

I purchased a [magic mouse battery charger](https://www.apple.com/battery-charger/) set today. It had a battery charger and 6 batteries. Now I put 2 batteries into the magic mouse and 4 batteries are in the box. My question is how to maximise the life of these batteries??

1. I use only one pair of batteries by charging / discharging and until the day the battery completely dies and no longer charges? (will that happen??) and then I switch to the next pair.
2. I use one pair and keep another pair in charging. Once this becomes completely drained, take the last pair from the box put it to charge, put the completely drained ones into the box and take the charged ones into the mouse. So i keep cycling like this?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lithium batteries do not like complete discharge, so do it at 10% or higher. You can leave them as long you wish in the charger, it will stop charging when full.

The battery charger it self has no limit on life time, yet again, it has to work harder if completely drained battery is to be charged.

If for some reason you have to leave the batteries on the shelf (in the box) for longer periods (months) then do it a 40% charge and keep them cool (15 Dgr. Celsius preferred).

Then when you notice the ones currently in use are at 20% start charging the replacement (from the box).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. I’m going to cycle all the batteries then so that they are always in use / always charged over 10%